# Gamesalad vs. Clickteam Fusion 2.5 - Rapid games prototyping

Tags: android, software-development, ios

I'm looking for a 2D game engine that would help me rapid prototype games (simple ones).

The tool I'm looking for should:

1. Be a graphical tool (I don't want to mess with code/scripts) and I don't care if I need to pay for it.
2. Have lots of games templates. I don't want to start from zero.
3. Should be cross-platform, at least iOS & Android. Mac is an option. No Windows support needed.
4. Analytics?
5. Social network integration (optional). I want for example to send requests through Facebook. I saw some tools have GameCenter option but I don't know what can I do with it (just scores or this feature also)

I just tried Gamesalad and it looks fine but have problems for example that I cannot add Analytics (which is very critical feature I don't really want to skip over) on the other hand it has a very good doc and low cost templates for full games, also tried to figure out Fusion 2.5 which has more or less same properties but looks old and with bad physics engine.

Does someone have experience with both and can compare between them? If there is a better tool I would be glad to know about. Also if I am missing something important in game creating that I didn't take into account.

Comment: 1) You say that the *tool* should be for iOS and Android, but, e.g., Gamesalad is for OS X and Windows. -- 2) Do you mean "Google Analytics" when you are referring to "Analytics"?

Comment: It is for android also (pro version). Yes, "google Analytics" is a good example.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the physics engine in Fusion 2.5 is superior to GameSalad. It is the Box2D system. You might want to check out Gamemaker Studio if you require all the features you mentioned, especially #4 and #5.